# Difference between these two functions in JS that I'm querying from firestore

Tags: javascript

So I was making a get user email function and came up with this.

This is the function that works perfectly.

```
const getMail = (users, userLoggedIn) =>
    users?.filter((userToFilter) => userToFilter !== userLoggedIn?.email)[0];

export default getMail;
```

Here is the 2nd function, that is not working as it's returning `undefined`.

```
const getMail = (users, userLoggedIn) => {
    users?.filter((userToFilter) => userToFilter !== userLoggedIn?.email)[0];
}

export default getMail;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second function is not returning anything, you will have to use `return` statement when wrapping the function body in curly `brackets`.

If you do not put brackets around your arrow function body the `return` statement can be ommitted. So the first function works.

In the second function you wrote curly brackets `{` and you would need to add a `return` statement.

So these functions are equal:

```
// #1
const getMail = (users, userLoggedIn) =>
  // curly brackets ommitted. THe function only consists of "1" statement 
  // and the result will automatically returned.
  users?.filter((userToFilter) => userToFilter !== userLoggedIn?.email)[0];

export default getMail;

// #2 
const getMail = (users, userLoggedIn) => {
    // you need to explicitly use "return" to return the value.
    return users?.filter((userToFilter) => userToFilter !== userLoggedIn?.email)[0];
}

export default getMail;
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. With Curly braces we have to return it explicitly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a shorthand without even knowing it. Without the {} after the arrow it will by default return whatever comes after the arrow. Otherwise you have to use the return statement.

```
const getMail = (users, userLoggedIn) => {
    return users?.filter((userToFilter) => userToFilter !== userLoggedIn?.email)[0];
}

export default getMail;
```

Comment: Yes, got it. With Curly braces we have to return it explicitly. Thanks for info.